# Stability, Support and Security Consideration of Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk

We are developing a hybrid_local mobile app for our salesforce customers using the Salesforce Mobile SDK. While doing this we are in the process of investigating some facts like stability and support of Mobile SDK, any security concerns of that, frequency of updates releasing, etc. Can anyone please provide any useful info on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sharing my thoughts based on my development experience with the Mobile SDK for last few years. Note - I have been developing Force.com mobile apps since the time when the Mobile SDK did not exist and you'd to pretty much write your own wrappers if you were doing any hybrid development or use tools such as zkSforce for native development.

**Stability/ Support** - In general, the best place to find support is the Mobile SDK github repos. I've often found bugs already filed for problems that I have faced. Else, if I have discovered a bug, I have filed it there myself. In general, I have received either an acknowledgement for a bug or a clarification on why Salesforce does not consider it as a bug. In general, 2.x versions are much more stable than the 1.x which were more evolutionary.

**Frequency of updates** - You can get first hand information for minor updates here - https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/releases Minor releases come out every 1-2 months but you for major releases 2.x you typically have 1-2 releases/ per year. It's taken nearly a year to go from Mobile SDK 1.x to 2.x

**Security** - If you go through the list of currently open issues on the Mobile SDK github repo, there's a lot of work ongoing in order to make the Smart Store more secure. There are certain limitations such as this - https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/392 which would be nice to fix but Salesforce won't do it in the name of security.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/intro_oauth.htm

Hybrid application developed using SDK provided by salesforce are really secure provided you use the features appropriately

> 1)For authentication use connected app feature and Oauth 2.0 for authentication .Never store username and password in the application .
>
> 2)If there are custom webservices developed using apex make sure to include "with sharing keyword " to respect security rules of your organisation
>
> 3)[Use Pin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/connected_apps_security_pin.htm) feature of connected apps to secure your data
>
> 4)If you are developing offline ability use smartsync.js to secure your offline data .
>
> 5)Manage your sessions of the application as documented below

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/hybrid_managing_sessions.htm

> 6)You can release vsersions of the app now starting summer 14 .Read release notes to gather more info
>
> 7)Connected apps can be configured for various profiles making it easier for distribution or authorization.
>
> 8)You can distribute your application through private appexchange feature which you need to contact salesforce or you can distribute through playstore or appstore

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mohith, any official note about the release notes or frequency of releases something like that?